# Using NSPredicate to add enable users to 'Favourite' objects, which will then appear in a separate TableView (without CoreData!)

Tags: swift, xcode, sorting, nspredicate, predicate

I currently have a tableView which is parsing and displaying data from a `JSON` file. When a cell is pressed, then the user is taken to a `detailView` screen to view further information.

I am now trying to set up a `Favourite` button within the `detailView`, so that users can press a button which will add the object to a `favouriteView` (this will be set up exactly the same as the `tableView`, but only show locations which have been favourited.

My understanding is that the best way to achieve this is to use `NSPredicate`. I have been looking around for hours and I can't seem to find a solution that does not use `CoreData` (although I have found a source which says that `CoreData` is not necessary). I would like to achieve the `Favourite` function without using `CoreData`.

I already have a favourite button set up in the `detailView`, which sets a variable `isFavourite` from `false` to `true`. Please see all the relevant code below.

**Sample JSON object**:

```
{
        "locations": [

            {
                "id": "0001",
                "name": "Helensburgh Tunnels",
                "type": "Tunnels, Beach, Views",
                "location": "Helensburgh, South Coast",
                "image": "Helensburgh-Tunnels.jpg",
                "activity": "Walking, photography, tunnelling",
                "isVisited": false,
                "isFavourite": false,
                "latitude": -34.178985,
                "longitude": 150.992867
            }
        ]
    }
```

**The favourite button I have set up in the detailView:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func favouriteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.location.isFavourite = self.location.isFavourite ? false : true

    print(location.isFavourite)

    // Favourite button
    if location.isFavourite == false {
        favouriteButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "starLine.png"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        favouriteButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "starFull.png"), for: .normal)
    }

}
```

How can I take all the objects which have been set to `isFavourite = true` and display them in a `tableView`?

This is a section of the `FavouriteLocationsViewController` class, what do I need to fix here to make it functional?

```
class FavouriteLocationsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var locations = [Location]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Remove the title of the back button
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        if let locationJson = readLocation(){
            if let locationArray = locationJson["locations"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                for location in locationArray{
                    locations.append(Location.init(locationInfo: location))
                }
                print(locations.count)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }

    // Filter to show only favourite locations
    func filterArrayOfDictonaryWithKeyValueUsingPredicate(arrOfDict: NSArray, keyOfDict: String, strSearchText: String) -> NSArray{
    let favouritePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == true")
    let arrResult = arrOfDict.filtered(using: favouritePredicate)
    return arrResult as NSArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to show only favourite data there?

you have array of dictonary as per you are showing above.

you can filter that array using predicate.

and you can get only object which isFavourite == "True"

use below function pass array of Location, Pass keyofDict - isFavourite

strSearchText - for your example use **true**

```
func filterArrayOfDictonaryWithKeyValueUsingPredicate(arrOfDict: NSArray, keyOfDict: String, strSearchText: String) -> NSArray{
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(keyOfDict) CONTAINS[C] %@", strSearchText)
        let arrResult = arrOfDict.filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        return arrResult as NSArray
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But where should I implement this? I tried it out and it did not seem to work. Please see the edits I made to the question, which now includes the code for my FavouriteLocationViewController.